# 403 Forbidden create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm

Начинаю работу над реакт-приложением:

```
mkdir shop-func
cd shop-func
npx create-react-app shop-func
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/avemrk/create-react-app - Permission denied
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-01T15_23_24_474Z-debug-0.log
```

Работаю на винде, node.js установлен:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\shop-func> node -v 
v18.16.0
PS C:\Users\Admin\shop-func> npm -v
9.5.1
PS C:\Users\Admin\shop-func> npx -v
9.5.1
```

Как это исправить? Бьюсь уже не первый день

Comment: А почему он хочет пойти в `npm.pkg.github.com`? Может у тебя что-то в `.npmrc` что-то странное написано?

Comment: npx идёт за пакетом на ваш гитхаб github.com/avemrk, почему?

Comment: директория пустая, файла .npmrc нет. Не знаю, почему он идтет на гитхаб...

Comment: а `npm config get registry` чего пишет?

Answer (score 0):

Помогла команда:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```